# Preservation of Kan extensions

Tags: ct.category-theory, kan-extension

I am currently studying the theory of kan extensions more seriously, but I'm surprised of the apparent absence if theorems of preservation/reflection. What I have in mind is something along the lines of if $K$ and $K'$ are two 2-categories and there is a 2-adjunction $K: L\dashv R :K'$, then $L(lan_i)\simeq lan_{L(i)}$ or if $F:K\to K'$ is 2-fully faithful, it reflects left and right extension. I am not directly asking whether these two examples are true statements, but more in general if there are results of this kind

Comment: Your question is akin to "classification" of functors preserving limits of particular shapes; and this problem usually does not have a tractable answer already in 1-categorical framework. There are plenty of results scattered among works of Benabou about fibrations which reflect Kan extensions, but I do not feel confident enough to state them in reasonable way without errors. The problem is that honest 2-adjunctions (not lax!) are very rigid structures, and mainly arise from fiberwise Yoneda embeddings.

Comment: There are probably results like this in Verity’s thesis, or in the work of Koudenburg on the formal category of virtual double categories.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I found the results Tim Campion is writing about and in general Verity's thesis seems pretty interesting, thank you for making me discover it!